# polynomial String s into a doubly linked list? parsing has to be done we have to find coeeficient and

Tags: java, parsing, doubly-linked-list, polynomials

Hello guys so I have to figure out how in the polynomial contructor how to take (String s) and place into a doubly linked list?  create a Term.
Then break down the expression into its parts and create Terms for each part.
These need to be combined and reordered to turn them into canonical form and stored in the DList.
parsing has to be done after. We need to use doubly linked list implementation to do canonicalization or manipulate the input strings then store in the linked list.

```
public class Polynomial extends AbstractPolynomial { 
public Polynomial(String s) { // complete this code
This I will have to parse eventually and bring create a node
        

/* This is what I've done so far so I'm trying to go through String and look for the - + and then get the index?  */
    
    int [] coef;
    int degree;
    int d = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
 
            if(s.charAt(i)=='-') {

            }
          if(s.charAt(i)== '+'){

          }
//All the way to here

        }


    }



    public Polynomial() { //we don't touch or modify
        super();
    }

    public AbstractPolynomial add(AbstractPolynomial p){ 
        AbstractPolynomial ans = new Polynomial();

        // complete this code
        return ans;
    }

    public AbstractPolynomial subtract(AbstractPolynomial p) { 
        AbstractPolynomial ans = new Polynomial();
        // complete this code
        return ans;
    }

    public AbstractPolynomial multiply(AbstractPolynomial p) { //we have to multiply
        AbstractPolynomial ans = new Polynomial();
        // complete this code
        return ans;
    }

    /****************
     * MAIN FUNCTION
     ****************/

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {//we don't touch or modify
        //Variables
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        AbstractPolynomial p, q;
        String testInput = "";
        //Custom test case
        if(scnr.hasNext()){
            testInput = scnr.nextLine();
            p = new Polynomial(testInput);
            testInput = scnr.nextLine();
            q = new Polynomial(testInput);
            System.out.println("User Input\n***************************");
            Utility.run(p, q);
        }
        //Default test case
        else{
            p = new Polynomial(" X^5");
            q = new Polynomial("X^2 - X + 1");
            System.out.println("Default Input\n***************************");
            Utility.run(p, q);
        }
    }
}

class Term {     // we don't touch or modify

    Double coefficient;
    int degree;

    public Term() {
        this(null, 0);
    }
    public boolean isPositive() {
        return coefficient > 0;
    }
    public Term(Double coefficient, int degree) {//we don't touch or modify
        this.coefficient = coefficient;
        this.degree = degree;
    }
    public Double getCoefficient() {//we don't touch or modify
        return coefficient;
    }
    public void setCoefficient(Double coefficient) {//we don't touch or modify
        this.coefficient = coefficient;
    }
    public int getDegree() {//we don't touch or modify
        return degree;
    }
    public void setDegree(int degree) {//we don't touch or modify
        this.degree = degree;
    }
    public String toString() {//we don't touch or modify
        String ans = "";
        if (coefficient.doubleValue() == 0) return "";
        if (degree == 0) return coefficient.toString();
        if (coefficient != 1) {
            if (coefficient == -1) ans += "-";
            else ans += coefficient + " ";
        }
        ans = ans + "X";
        if (degree == 1) return ans;
        return ans + "^" + degree;
    }
}
class DList<T> {//we don't touch or modify

    private DNode<T> header, trailer;
    private int size;

    public DList() {
        size = 0;
        header = new DNode<T>(null, null, null);
        trailer = new DNode<T>(null, header, null);
        header.setNext(trailer);
    }

    // utility methods

    public int size() {//we don't touch or modify
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {//we don't touch or modify
        return size == 0;
    }

    // give clients access to nodes, but not to the header or trailer

    public DNode<T> getFirst() throws Exception {//we don't touch or modify
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new Exception("Empty");
        return header.getNext();
    }

    public DNode<T> getLast() throws Exception {//we don't touch or modify
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new Exception("Empty");
        return trailer.getPrev();
    }

    public DNode<T> getNext(DNode<T> v) throws Exception {//we don't touch or modify
        DNode<T> ans = v.getNext();
        if (ans == null || ans == trailer)
            throw new Exception("No such node");
        return ans;
    }

    public DNode<T> getPrev(DNode<T> v) throws Exception {//we don't touch or modify
        DNode<T> ans = v.getPrev();
        if (ans == null || ans == header)
            throw new Exception("No such node");
        return ans;
    }

    // methods to change the list

    public void addBefore(T d, DNode<T> v) {//we don't touch or modify
        DNode<T> u = v.getPrev();
        DNode<T> x = new DNode<T>(d, u, v);
        u.setNext(x);
        v.setPrev(x);
        size++;
    }

    public void addAfter(T d, DNode<T> v) {//we don't touch or modify
        DNode<T> w = v.getNext();
        DNode<T> x = new DNode<T>(d, v, w);
        v.setNext(x);
        w.setPrev(x);
        size++;
    }

    public void addFirst(T d) {//we don't touch or modify
        addAfter(d, header);
    }

    public void addLast(T d) {//we don't touch or modify
        addBefore(d, trailer);
    }

    public T remove(DNode<T> v) throws Exception {//we don't touch or modify
        if (v == header || v == trailer)
            throw new Exception("Sentinel");
        DNode<T> u = v.getPrev();
        DNode<T> w = v.getNext();
        w.setPrev(u);
        u.setNext(w);
        size--;
        return v.getData();
    }

    // LinkedList testing methods:

    public String toString() {//we don't touch or modify
        String ans = "";
        DNode<T> n = header;
        ans += "(H)<-->";
        do {
            n = n.getNext();
            if (n == trailer)
                ans += "(T)";
            else
                ans += (n.getData() + "<-->");
        } while (n != trailer);
        return ans;
    }
}
abstract class AbstractPolynomial { //we don't touch or modify

    DList<Term> data = null;
    public AbstractPolynomial() {
        data = new DList<>();
    }
    public final String toString() {
        String ans = "";
        boolean starting = true;
        try {
            DNode<Term> n = data.getFirst();
            while (n != null) {
                if (!starting && n.getData().isPositive()) ans += " +";
                starting = false;
                ans += " " + n.getData().toString();
                n = data.getNext(n);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (starting) return "0";
        }
        return ans;
    }
    abstract public AbstractPolynomial add(AbstractPolynomial p);
    abstract public AbstractPolynomial subtract(AbstractPolynomial p);
    abstract public AbstractPolynomial multiply(AbstractPolynomial p);
}

class Utility {// we don't touch or modify


    public static void run(AbstractPolynomial p, AbstractPolynomial q) throws Exception {//dont touch or modify
        System.out.println("Polynomials\np = " + p + "\nq = " + q);
        System.out.println("Sum " + p.add(q));
        System.out.println("Difference " + p.subtract(q));
        System.out.println("Product " + p.multiply(q));
    }
}
class DNode<T> { //we don't touch or modify
    private T data;
    private DNode<T> prev, next;

    public DNode(T d, DNode<T> p, DNode<T> n) {
        data = d;
        next = n;
        prev = p;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public DNode<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to take the input as a string and separate it, you should try using the split() method in the String class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)